# Wordpress - get_post_status filter is ignored in categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I want to override the `get_post_status` function to mark posts `public` or `private` depending on the user agent info and post data (basically, hide some specific posts from some specific unauthorized users). Here are MCVE demonstrating my problem:

```
add_filter( 'get_post_status', function( $post_status, $post ) {
    return 'private';
}, 10, 2 );
```

I'm expecting this code to make all of the posts `private`. This works then I'm directly opening the post page, but on the "category" page this post is still visible.

What else should I override to make this example work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something else to accomplish this - for example, checking if user is logged in and/or has a certain privilege (and based on that sort out the posts you don't want to show to the user).

Your code snippet, as you pointed out - works on a single post page (because the $ID is set as a global variable - but this will hide all posts from all users ... always :)

Have a look [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

Comment: I've noted above that this is only an example. And actually it _should_ hide all posts from all unauthorized users. But something goes wrong and it hides posts only on post page, but not from categories/etc.